# How to code future data with SKlearn KMeans model

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, k-means

I use KMeans to identify clusters and assign each data row to one of the clusters.  That's great for the data I'm working with for the moment.  Suppose I want to code a new dataset to conform to the same clusters?  Is there a way to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, in your dataset you should have the same data structure as before. Then you can use predict(data) method to get clusters for new data

Comment: Thank you, makes perfect sense.